# Is there any way to optimise this JavaScript further (comparing current time to opening hours)?

Tags: javascript

I am setting up some JavaScript to compare the current time to a venue's opening and closing hours (potentially different each day, so different var for each day).

Here's what I have so far:

```
// Compare current time to today's hours
if (day === 1 && time > monOpen && time < monClose) {
    venueIsOpen();
} else if (day === 2 && time > tuesOpen && time < tuesClose) {
    venueIsOpen();
} else if (day === 3 && time > wedOpen && time < wedClose) {
    venueIsOpen();
} else if (day === 4 && time > thursOpen && time < thursClose) {
    venueIsOpen();
} else if (day === 5 && time > friOpen && time < friClose) {
    venueIsOpen();
} else if (day === 6 && time > satOpen && time < satClose) {
    venueIsOpen();
} else if (day === 0 && time > sunOpen && time < sunClose) {
    venueIsOpen();
} else {
    venueIsClosed();
}
```

Obviously very straightforward - is there any way to optimise this?

Comment: Why do you have so many variables? Shouldn't you put the open and close times in an array of size 7? An "optimisation" would be quite straightforward then.

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Review/refactoring requests are offtopic here. Go to [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, we can combine a load of those `if` statements:

```
// Compare current time to today's hours
if (day === 1 && time > monOpen && time < monClose ||
    day === 2 && time > tuesOpen && time < tuesClose ||
    day === 3 && time > wedOpen && time < wedClose ||
    day === 4 && time > thursOpen && time < thursClose ||
    day === 5 && time > friOpen && time < friClose ||
    day === 6 && time > satOpen && time < satClose ||
    day === 0 && time > sunOpen && time < sunClose) {
        venueIsOpen();
} else {
    venueIsClosed();
}
```

That's still quite ugly, right? But there's some logic in there... We could use arrays for the open / close times:

```
var open = [sunOpen, monOpen, tuesOpen, wedOpen, thursOpen, friOpen, satOpen],
    close = [sunClose, monClose, tuesClose, wedClose, thursClose, friClose, satClose];

if(time > open[day] && time < close[day])
    venueIsOpen();
else
    venueIsClosed();
```

Or, even shorter using a [ternary condition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator):

```
(time > open[day] && time < close[day] ? venueIsOpen : venueIsClosed)();
```

Comment: That ternary is ugly. But if you want to go for it, then it should be `(time > open[day] && time < close[day] ? venueIsOpen : venueIsClosed)()`

Comment: @Bergi: You saw nothing ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way that could shorten your code:

```
// These are the 7 days of the week
var openings = [
{opening: 1,close: 2},
{opening: 2,close: 4},
{opening: 5,close: 7},
{opening: 1,close: 5},
{opening: 1,close: 3},
{opening: 2,close: 9},
{opening: 1,close: 2}
];

// loop through all of them
for(var i=0, l=openings.length; i<l; i++) {
    // if the current time is bigger than the current day opening time and smaller than the current closing time call venueIsOpen(), otherwise call venueIsClosed()
    (openings[day].opening < time && openings[day].close > time) ? venueIsOpen() : venueIsClosed();   
}
```

Comment: `var openings = { open: [], close: [] }` would be shorter, but this is also a good option.

Comment: True, I just think the other way around makes it more readable but since the question is about optimization I guess you're right.